# Edit page headers

Tags: formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to edit my page titles with fancyhdr package. I want the top left of the page to present [section number]. [section name]
in boldface and small caps. for example:

**3.2. PYTHAGORAS THEOREM**

I noticed that `\leftmark` puts the small-caps letter in a nice way (with proper space between them, and also straight, which doesn't happen with some other methods) but if I try to edit it

```
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{...}
```

I lose the small caps.
What is the best way to achieve what I want?

An example code to build on:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\bfseries \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{My first chapter}
    \blindtext
    \section{My first section}
    \blindtext[10]  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using formatting commands within `fancyhdr` commands, such as in `\fancyhead`, instead of redefining `\leftmark`. More important, you need to use a font with bold small caps. The default font doesn't have small caps. This could be the reason why you notice you loose small caps when switching to bold.

In your example, with `kpfonts`, you would get bold small caps text in the header:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\textbf{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
```

[image: heading with bold small caps]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but how do I produce a heading in the form I mentioned in my question? in my example code, it should be: **1.1. MY FIRST SECTION** where ** denotes bold letters. I don't know which command would get the appropriate [section name], which is "My First Section" here. Also, is it possible to apply the small-caps with the computer-modern font? or which other fonts support it?

Comment: @Andro The section name is usually in \rightmark. Try: `\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}`. Regarding bold small caps in CM try: `\usepackage{bold-extra}` however I doubt it looks great - but see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. it does indeed write what I want. regarding the font - I can't make computer modern present small-caps and bfseries together at all. I took the idea for headings from this document: http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_operator.pdf is it not a computer-modern font?

Comment: The fonts in the link you provide sure look like CM. However, the text in the header line is "ordinary" bold, not small-caps bold. Some font families that feature small caps & bold glyphs are `mathptmx` and `txfonts` (Times New Roman-like fonts) and `mathpazo` and `pxfonts` (Palatino-like fonts).

Comment: @Mico what is the difference between "ordinary" capital letters and small-caps? How do you produce letters such as in that document? I notice that small-caps are not "straight" in the sense that not all letters have the same size, is that intentional? and is the fact that SC and BF don't naturally work together - a bug?

Comment: Setting a string in small-cap glyphs affects the appearance of "lowercase" letters -- they look like, well, small versions of uppercase letters -- but it does not affect letters that are already in uppercase. One can distinguish between a string of all-lowercase letters set in small caps versus a string of all-uppercase letters by comparing them with the height of (lining) numerals (0...9): If the letters and numerals are the same height, you're dealing with uppercase letters. The absence of glyphs that are both bold and small-caps is not a bug, but a conscious decision of the font designer.